# Бот ВК игнорирует сообщения в беседе

Tags: python, вконтакте, бот

Бот ВК игнорирует сообщения в беседе. При попытке написать боту в лс выдает эксепшн

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'peer_id'

все пермишны у бота есть

```
import vk_api
import requests
import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse   import quote

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='тут мой токен')

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, тут мой айди)
commands = ['рио','помощь', 'етс']

def send_rio_message_dm(char_name):
    if string_list[0] == commands[0]:
        rq_string = 'https://raider.io/api/v1/characters/profile?region=eu&realm=soulflayer&name=' + quote(char_name) + '&fields=mythic_plus_scores_by_season%3Acurrent'
        request = requests.get(rq_string)
        json_data = json.loads(request.text)
        if 'statusCode' in json_data:
            vk.messages.send(
            peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
            random_id=event.random_id,
            message='Неверно указано имя персонажа'
            )
            return
        vk.messages.send(
            peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
            random_id=event.random_id,
            message=json_data['mythic_plus_scores_by_season'][0]['scores']['all']
        )
    else:
        vk.messages.send(
            peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
            random_id=event.random_id,
            message='Неверный формат запроса'
        )

def send_rio_message_chat(char_name):
    if string_list[0] == commands[0]:
        rq_string = 'https://raider.io/api/v1/characters/profile?region=eu&realm=soulflayer&name=' + quote(char_name) + '&fields=mythic_plus_scores_by_season%3Acurrent'
        request = requests.get(rq_string)
        json_data = json.loads(request.text)
        if 'statusCode' in json_data:
            vk.messages.send(
            peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
            random_id=event.random_id,
            message='Неверно указано имя персонажа'
            )
            return
        vk.messages.send(
            peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
            random_id=event.random_id,
            message=json_data['mythic_plus_scores_by_season'][0]['scores']['all']
        )
    else:   
        vk.messages.send(
            peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
            random_id=event.random_id,
            message='Неверный формат запроса'
        )

for event in longpoll.listen():
    print(event)
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        if commands[0] in event.text:
            string_list = event.text.split(' ')
            current_char_name = 'Имя персонажа не указано'
            if len(string_list)>1:
                current_char_name = string_list[1].capitalize()
                if event.from_user:
                    send_rio_message_dm(current_char_name)
                elif event.from_chat:
                    send_rio_message_chat(current_char_name)
            else:
                vk.messages.send(
                    peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
                    random_id=event.random_id,
                    message='Неверный формат запроса'
                )
        if event.text == commands[1]:
            vk.messages.send(
                    peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
                    random_id=event.random_id,
                    message='Список команд: рио <имя персонажа>, помощь, фарк'
                )
```

Comment: Мне кажется вам надо передавать *event* в функцию *send_rio_message_dm*

Answer (score 0):

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import requests
import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse   import quote

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='token')

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "id")

for event in longpoll.listen():
    #print(event)
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.obj.text:
        if event.obj.text == 'test':
            vk.messages.send(
                peer_id = event.obj.from_id,
                message = "response_test",
                random_id = get_random_id()
            )
```

Немного поправил Ваш код, данный код работает на версии API: 5.92
В лс работает, в беседе не проверял. Но возможно вы просто забыли выдать права администратора в беседе, или права на прочтение сообщений.
Функции которые у вас были, добавьте сами.

Comment: И да. event в функции нужно передать